# css refactoring tool

Tags: css, refactoring

i have taken over a website that has tons of css files and lots of inline css as well.  Is there any tool that can show me a visualization of how this stuff is organized as i have a strong feeling that.  Many pages are bringing in more css than necessary

Also, i want to remove all the inline formatting as well into css files.  Is there any refactoring tool that does even this by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 dev tools can show you all CSS inheritance tree (including files where this particular style is defined in)

Firefox has tons of plugins that can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question - I don't know of a true refactoring tool for CSS. One that I've used to create and preview CSS easily is [TopStyle](http://www.topstyle4.com/) - I'm on v3.5 Pro, and they've got v4 out now. There may be better or less expensive alternatives out there; I'm not an expert.

You might also want to check out Firebug: http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver, it can convert inline css to external css file.
also it can view all css files and its rules in a outline view, and you can easily rename all of it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Dust-Me Selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/) Firefox extension could help you find CSS that isn't used at all, it's a good first step.